# Will a self hosted web api at port :8080 conflict if more than one app uses the same port? (Winrt)

Tags: c#, .net, api, windows-runtime

I'm working on adding live tiles to my windows 8 app, and the best solution for me will be a web hosted api to send updates to the tiles.

My concern is that I may end up using a port that's already in use by another app.

So I'm wondering if it's even an issue.  Or if there is a way that I can check this before assigning the port.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Only one application can bind to a port at a time.  If something is already listening on port 8080 when your application tries to bind to it and listen your program will throw an exception.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is an issue. Two application cannot bind to the same port simultaneously.